# How do I found a corporation?

Tags: civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

I'm trying to found the *Creative Constructions* corporation using a Great Engineer unit.

I've researched both the Corporation and Combustion techs. My civilization has access to Iron and Copper. I've moved my Great Engineer into a city 3 squares away from a copper mine, but the *Construct (Creative Constructions)* option is still disabled.

What else do I need to do to be able to construct a corporate headquarters?

Comment: If you hover the mouse over the "Construct" button which is shaded. There should be a tooltip saying whats wrong?

Comment: Did another civ found the corporation already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot found a corporation while the "State Property" civic is active. 
I have used freehand circles below to indicate the nature of the [problem.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rS401CI7TZg)

[image: Screenshot showing that corporations have no effect while the State Property civic is active.]